# Use knockoutjs in Ui component of Admin form

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, layout, uicomponent, knockoutjs

I have created a form using UI component on Admin side. If i want to add a .phtml then i can add the file this way.

```
<htmlContent name="driven_form_design"> 
  <block class="Magento\Backend\Block\Template" template="Avesh_Faq::temp.phtml" name="testing_tmp" />
<htmlContent>
```

Inside temp.phtml

```
<div>Hello World<div>

<div id="custom-component" data-bind="scope:'customcomponent'">
  <!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
  <script type="text/x-magento-init">
    {
       "#custom-component": {
          "Magento_Ui/js/core/app": {
             "components": {
                 "customcomponent": {
                    "component": "Avesh_Faq/js/custom-component"
                  }
              }
          }
       }
    }
  </script>
 </div>
```

The Custom custom-component.js file includes

```
define(['jquery', 'uiComponent', 'ko'], function ($, Component, ko) {
    'use strict';
    return Component.extend({
        defaults: {
            template: 'Avesh_Faq/knockout-test'
        },
        initialize: function () {
            this._super();
        }
    });
  }
);
```

And the knockout-test.html file contains

```
<div>My Name is Avesh</div>
```

## The Expected Output should been

Hello World

My Name is Avesh

## What i am getting is

Hello World

## No errors in console neither on the site.

## But

If i use this same block directly in the layout file then it works. What is wrong with UI component. What is the correct way that my Knockoutjs will run in UI componnet file?